# Exception when getting Collection<Long> values using Hibernate - ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got List propertyIds. And I want to get propertyIds by Collections. This is my code:

```
Collection<Long> propertyIds = externalTaxManager.getPropertyIdsByTaxId(id);  //Return type must be Collection<Long>
```

This is my DAOImpl,

```
public Collection<Long> getPropertyIdsByTaxId(Long externalTaxId) {
    SQLQuery query = currentSession().createSQLQuery("select b.OMH_PROPERTY_ID from OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX a , " +
                "OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_PROP_XREF b\n" +
                "where a.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID=b.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID and a.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID = :externalTaxId ")
                .addScalar("OMH_PROPERTY_ID" , LongType.INSTANCE);
        query.setParameter("externalTaxId", externalTaxId);
        Collection<BigDecimal> propertyIdsList = (Collection<BigDecimal>) query.list();
    Long val = null;
    Collection<Long> expRes = new HashSet<Long>();
    for(BigDecimal values : propertyIdsList){
       val = values.longValue();
       expRes.add(val);
    }
    return expRes;
}
```

above Query returns 500+ values in associating with externalTaxId.

Exception thrown is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long.
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: What is the definition of the column `OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_PROP_XREF.OMH_PROPERTY_ID`?  It is being mapped to `BigDecimal` somewhere, and that is not castable to `Long`.

Comment: OMH_PROPERTY_ID  is  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)

Comment: That's too long for a `Long`, so Hibernate is returning it as a BigDecimal.  Change your collection to `Collection<BigDecimal>`.  Do you really need a 38 digit ID?

Comment: Actually I need to convert it into a Collection<Long> as I have to pass Collection<Long> value to a dependent system of my project.That application accepts only Collection<Long> value. So is there a way to convert the value?

Comment: @yogesh I think you should answer your own question (instead of editing your it) if no one does because fixing the problem in question will confuse people reading it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet worked for me as expected.

```
   public Collection<Long> getPropertyIdsByTaxId(Long externalTaxId) {
        SQLQuery query = currentSession().createSQLQuery("select b.OMH_PROPERTY_ID from OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX a , " +
                "OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_PROP_XREF b\n" +
                "where a.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID=b.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID and a.OMH_EXTERNAL_TAX_ID = :externalTaxId ")
                .addScalar("OMH_PROPERTY_ID", LongType.INSTANCE);
        query.setParameter("externalTaxId", externalTaxId);
        Collection<BigDecimal> propertyIdsList = (Collection<BigDecimal>) query.list();
        Long propertyIdsListValue = null;
        Collection<Long> propertyIds = new HashSet<Long>();
        for (BigDecimal propertyId : propertyIdsList) {
            propertyIdsListValue = propertyId.longValue();
            propertyIds.add(propertyIdsListValue);
        }
        return propertyIds;
    }
```

Comment: Do not post subsequent questions using the Answer box.  [edit] your original post instead.  Please copy this to your post and delete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

look at your expected return type:

```
Collection<Long>
```

but the DB returns :

```
Collection<BigDecimal>
```

so ,you should change your code to:

```
Collection<BigDecimal> propertyIdsList =  query.list();
```

then try to cast BigDecimal to Long in other way;

^_^ forgive my poor English..

Comment: Actually I need to convert it into a Collection<Long> as I have to pass Collection<Long> value to a dependent system of my project.That application accepts only Collection<Long> value. So is there a way to convert the value?

Comment: You should iterate over the returned array and copy to one with the proper type.  However, what are you going to do when one of the returned value is too large to fit in a `Long`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Please see the answer I posted . Is it the right way I can proceed

Comment: @JimGarrison I have updated DaoImpl, Is it the right way you suggested to do

Comment: You must fetch it from the database into a `Collection<BigDecimal>` and then convert each element to `Long`.

Comment: maybe you can try BigDecimal.longValue() in foreach.

Comment: But,if you need a 38 digit ID,it's not a good solution. Long's max length is 19, accepted value:  -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

Comment: Hi @star and Jim I have edited my question DAOImpl class. Can you please check for it now? I have changed the code as per your suggestion

Comment: you should put expRes.add(val) in foreach.  And,you should make sure digit ID's length must less then 19,if not ,it's a serious problem.

Comment: @star , I have edited . It will return the values I expected ?  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: sorry not length, is value, less then 9223372036854775807

Comment: Okay. The values don't exceed more than 19 digits.

Comment: @star Can I convert above SQLQuery to Criteria object. I am new to hibernate . Also the query contains Joins so it became difficult for me

Comment: @JimGarrison Can I convert above SQLQuery to Criteria object. I am new to hibernate . Also the query contains Joins so it became difficult for me

Comment: @yogesh [the hibernate document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e40)  will help you.